# How to change jetty port for Scalatra

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatra

I see in numerous places phrases like:

> Changing the port in development  Add

```
port in container.Configuration := 8081
```

> to project/build.scala

But ***where*** in build.scala?  Here is the vanilla build.scala. It is unclear where that addition should go:

```
object KeywordsBuild extends Build {
  val Organization = "com.blazedb"
  ..    
  lazy val project = Project (
    "keywords",
    file("."),
    settings = ScalatraPlugin.scalatraSettings ++ scalateSettings ++ Seq(
      organization := Organization,
      name := Name,
      version := Version,
      ..
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % ScalatraVersion,
         ..
        "javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % "3.1.0" % "provided"
      ),
      scalateTemplateConfig in Compile <<= (sourceDirectory in Compile){            base =>
        Seq(
          TemplateConfig(
            base / "webapp" / "WEB-INF" / "templates",
            Seq.empty,  /* default imports should be added here */
            Seq(
              Binding("context", "_root_.org.scalatra.scalate.ScalatraRenderContext", importMembers = true, isImplicit = true)
            ),  /* add extra bindings here */
            Some("templates")
          )
```

Wherever I have tried to put it the following error message happens:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /shared/wfdemo/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
/shared/wfdemo/build.sbt:1: error: not found: value port
port in container.Configuration := 8081
```

Comment: What scalatra-sbt version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to add to

> build.sbt

So the documentation appears to be incorrect - or at the least misleading.

```
$cat build.sbt
val myPort = 9090

jetty(port = myPort)
```

Comment: Whether I put your `build.sbt` in the root Scalatra project directory or in `project/`, I see an error, `error: not found: value jetty
jetty(port = myPort)`. Halp?

Comment: Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34958768/current-procedure-to-change-default-port-in-scalatras-scalatra-sbt-giter8-templ

Answer (score 0):

create a file JettyLauncher.scala under /src/main/scala :

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.{DefaultServlet, ServletContextHandler}
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext
import org.scalatra.servlet.ScalatraListener

object JettyLauncher {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val port = System.getProperty("port","8090").toInt

  val server = new Server(port)
  val context = new WebAppContext()
  context setContextPath "/"
  context.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp")
  context.addEventListener(new ScalatraListener)
  context.addServlet(classOf[DefaultServlet], "/")

  server.setHandler(context)

  server.start
  server.join
}
}
```

make sure your plugins.sbt under project/ has :

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-twirl" % "1.3.13")
addSbtPlugin("org.scalatra.sbt" % "sbt-scalatra" % "1.0.2")
addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" % "xsbt-web-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

agains sbt = 0.13.16

do an sbt clean compile assembly package (now that you have an sbt-assembly plugin)

run your jar as follows :

```
java -Dport=8081 -Dname=sameer -jar /Users/sumit/Documents/repos/inner/paytm-insurance-ml-api/serving-layers/model-serving-movies-cp/target/scala-2.11/model-serving-movies-cp-assembly-0.1.jar
```

This worked for me :

```
13:11:18.326 [main] INFO  o.e.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started ServerConnector@509dbdcf{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8081}
13:11:18.327 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @1312ms
```